# moment's isSameOrBefore and isSameOrAfter return "is not a function" when called from a moment and passed a moment

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

Why do **momentjs** `isSameOrBefore` and `isSameOrAfter` functions does not work for data which `isBefore` and `isAfter` work for?

Here are some very simple isolated examples where `isSameOrBefore` and `isSameOrAfter` does not work:

```
moment("2018-10-12 10:44:01").isSameOrBefore(moment("2018-10-12 10:44:00"))
TypeError: moment(...).isSameOrBefore is not a function [Learn More]

moment("2018-10-12 10:44:01").isSameOrAfter(moment("2018-10-12 10:44:02"))
TypeError: moment(...).isSameOrAfter is not a function [Learn More]
```

But yet with the same kind of data, `isBefore` and `isAfter` work fine:

```
moment("2018-10-12 10:44:01").isBefore(moment("2018-10-12 10:44:00"))
false
moment("2018-10-12 10:44:01").isAfter(moment("2018-10-12 10:44:02"))
false
moment("2018-10-12 10:44:00").isBefore(moment("2018-10-12 10:44:01"))
true
moment("2018-10-12 10:44:02").isAfter(moment("2018-10-12 10:44:01"))
true
```

Comment: Which version of moment are you using? [`isSameOrBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/) was introduced in 2.11.0

Comment: Ah, well I'm using 2.9.0 so that would explain it!  What is strange though is that TypeScript gave me the Intellisense for the two methods and if I F12 on them it takes me to moment.d.ts with `Type definitions for Moment.js 2.11.1` at the top as a comment.  I'll try upgrading the NuGet package for the project anyway, thanks!

Comment: Well the update hasn't fixed the issue even after a browser restart and hard refresh.  The .d.ts file still has the same comment about version 2.11.1 at the top also but yet moment-with-locales.js, moment-with-locales.min.js, moment.js and moment.min.js have all changed.

Comment: Nevermind, it was Waterfox caching the old scripts!  I had to Ctrl + F5 once again after having restarted the browser.  Version 2.23.0 is what I am now using and it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this for me was to update to version 2.23.0 of Moment.js.  I was mislead by my `moment.d.ts` file which, for unknown reasons, was for version 2.11.1 of Moment.js instead as opposed to the version I had installed (version 2.9.0).

After the update, be sure to check in the browser's debugger's file explorer for the moment.js file and verify that it matches up with the one in your project - if it doesn't, at least in Firefox/Waterfox, try restarting the browser then pressing Ctrl + F5 on the page of your project you're having the issue with.

This has been a lesson for me to not put so much faith in the type-safety of TypeScript!

Answer (score 4):

The `isSameOrBefore` and `isSameOrAfter` methods were introduced since version **2.11.0** : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/

You can upgrade the version and try this:

```
moment('2018-10-12 10:44:01').isSameOrBefore('2018-10-12 10:44:00')
```

Comment: No, please note that `isSameOrBefore` (like other query functions) accepts: `Moment`, `String`, `Number`, `Date`, `Array`as first parameter (and an optional `String` as second parameter)